# AForge.net or EmguCV AutoFocus

Tags: vb.net, emgucv, aforge

I am wondering if anyone has applied a contrast based autofocus technique using AForge or EmguCV. I have a Nikon D5300 DSLR which I am going to connect to a lead screw and servo and bring the camera forwards and backwards to try and find the appropriate points along the Z axis which have some 'focus' or 'contrast' information.

The issue is that since I am doing high magnification work, the depth of field is fairly shallow which means that there may actually be more than one focus point.

The idea was to use a live view image, and to move through the Z axis from a start to finish point, recording the Z position and then measure if any of the image is in focus. If this is the case then it would 'remember' those positions for later.

Once I have the positions, I would turn off the live view, move to each position and capture a high resolution image which I would then focus stack into one image.

So I am curious if anyone has done something similar where they are trying to determine if there is detail in any part of the image which should be captured to be included in the final focus stacked image.

Thanks